# Toggle variable upon onClick in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a default state in my constructor

```
this.state {
    showModal:false
}
```

then how can I toggle the value without declaring a function, but straight away do that in JSX? I found it's too much of code to do it in a function. Can't it be more simple just do it like

```
render(){
    return(<div onClick={()=>this.setState({showModal:!showModal})}></div>)
}
```

But I got error of syntax error in my JSX above. Why?

Comment: @bejado won't work too

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, React state is maintained in the `this.state` property, thus you need to reference `this.state.showModal`, not `this.showModal`.

The correct way to do this:

```
<div onClick={() =>
    this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})}>
</div>
```

As for doing this only using JSX (without declaring a function), that isn't possible. JSX *is* JavaScript.